# Challenges in upgrading desktop application in Swing to JAVAFX

Tags: javafx

I have a telecom desktop application(EMS) developed in java Swing. Its an old application developed and maintained in swing from last 10 years. Now we are planning to update GUI pages using javaFX technology for better and clean look & feel.

I had gone through various stack overflow discussion stating difference between javaFX and Swing. Please someone help me to understand the challenges in upgrading to javaFX GUI considering below constraints:-

-Application needs to be deployed in Unix, Solaris, HPUX, MAC and window 7/8 OS

-Some third party jars are also used along with JRE

-Current supported JRE is java 7

-There could be a plan to support android/apple/blackberry handheld devices

-We are not using Database for persistence but live data to display.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is based on the detailed constraints of the question and is not a general comment on Swing to JavaFX ports.  Parts of this answer will inevitably get outdated, perhaps fairly quickly.

Given your constraints, you can't upgrade your application to JavaFX.

Solaris and HPUX are not [supported deployment platforms](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) for JavaFX and that is unlikely to change.

The only way you could get JavaFX to work on Solaris or HPUX would be to use an unsupported configuration such as running a VirtualBox VM on Solaris or HPUX as the host OS, and in the VM run a supported OS, such as RedHat 6 or Oracle Linux 6, then running your JavaFX application within the supported OS - this may or may not work.

Also, I think it unlikely JavaFX would be ported to run on blackberries any time soon.  There are [ports of JavaFX](http://javafxports.org/page/home) to other mobile platforms, and they work for simple applications.  I haven't tried them and think of JavaFX applications targeting such ports as a bit experimental at this stage.  Such ports do not execute on an Oracle JVM and JRE, so if you use external libraries they have to be compatible with the port runtime (e.g. the Android Development Kit, RoboVM libs etc).

If you ported parts of your application to JavaFX, I would recommend running on a minimum of Java 8 rather than Java 7.  Many bugs were fixed and many new features were implemented in JavaFX for Java 8.  In particular for a Swing->JavaFX port, the integration capabilities of JavaFX and Swing were improved in Java 8 with [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html).  To help ensure your target systems have the correct runtime installed you can package your application with an appropriate JRE as a [self-contained application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm).

Of course, if you can relax your constraints a bit, there are [many positive points for JavaFX](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180497/75821).